# ADO function copying numbers as text

Tags: excel, vba, ado

Ado function that copies and pastes data from Excel spreadsheet is pasting numbers as text. How can I get the function to paste as number value?

```
' Copy data
If SourceSheet = "" Then
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If


' Initialise recordset
Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Paste data
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I've tried Alyssa' solution and also added to it by selecting the full TargetRange and applying the correct formatting. However as can be seen below the format is applied, but the cell is still stored as text.

E.g.

```
TargetRange.NumberFormat = "0.0\%"
```

[Excel picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSa5c.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add number formatting of the cells:

```
TargetRange.Cells(x, y).NumberFormat = "0"
```

The above line makes the cell format as a `Number`

So your final code will look like:

```
' Paste data
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
    Else
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Alyssa. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've edited my original post.

Comment: @JJJ I believe you are looking for `Range(...).NumberFormat = "0.00"` for that column you have highlighted in the picture. Also, make sure `TargetRange.Cells(2, 1)` is referring to the correct cells you want to format. You might need an `.offset()`.